# jquery to signify if an option is not selected

Tags: php, html

I would like to add a small code snip to check out whether an option is selected
This usually is easily done if the page is html, now my code snip looks something like this

```php
echo "<td>Language</td>";
echo "<td><select id='language' name='language'>
            <option value=''>Select...</option>
            <option value='en_US'>English(US)</option>
            <option value='en_AU'>English(AU)</option>
            <option value='en_UK'>English(UK)</option>
          </select><span id="info"></span>
      </td>";
```

if it is html

```js
<script>
   $('#language').change()
   {
     if('Select...'==$('#language').text())
     {
        $('#info').html("Please select a value...");
     }
   }
</script>
```

[**UPDATE**]

I would like to add that the above php source code used to generate html code is put in a form tag that is

```
echo "<form action='checkdb.php' method='POST'>
    // all above and more
    </form>"
```

the page checkdb.php used the posted data to update database.

How can I add in the jquery code piece as mentioned in the current file (the file with the html code is being generated) ? I am thinking as people once told me that javascript can't be called in the middle of the php execution and I wonder if I may need to use ajax get function. Please offer some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Listen, and respond to, the change even on our select
$("#language").on("change", function(e){
  // Set the html content of our info element
  $("#info").html(function(){
    // If the selected option has no value, ask to select a value
    return e.target.value === "" ? "Please select a value." : "" ;
  });
// Trigger upon page load
}).trigger("change");
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/owaqaz/2/edit

Note the last line, `$.trigger("change")` - this will cause the page to immediately populate the `#info` element if the select element currently has no value.

Answer (score 1):

Change your jQuery to:

```
$('#language').change(function() {
    if ('Select...' == $('#language option:selected').text()) {
        $('#info').html("Please select a value...");
    }
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4uz3W/)**.

*Update*: Or a more brief version:

jQuery:

```
$('#language').change(function() {
    $('#info').html(('Select...' == $('#language option:selected').text()) ? "Please select a value...":"");
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/4uz3W/1/)**.

Comment: Or the cleaner alternative using the value: `if($('#language').val() == '') ...`

Comment: @bfavaretto if he is looking for value and not for text

Comment: @bfavaretto - that won't work since the "Select..." option has a blank value. Of course, the OP could add one but as the question stands it would fail.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but what was your question?
A PHP page turns into a HTML Page after processing (a user never sees the PHP source code), and you can easily use javascript to check for the value.

Comment: Thanks but it the html source is generated by php code and is all things is done in php because later when that html source is shown, I again have to handle database table right in that source.